# Translation of "run for food" (charity event)

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase-request

In English, *Run for Food* is used as a title for charity events. Food (for others) is a reward for running, nobody is actually physically running to retrieve food.

How would that translate to German correctly? *Laufen für Essen* or *Lauf für Essen?* Or will either variation work?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use any of your proposals. I would call it:

> Essenslauf

Because the German noun »der Lauf« is the English noun »the run«, and »der Essenslauf« literally is »the food run«

But when, however, you combine *Essen* and *Lauf/Laufen*: It always sounds weird in German.

There are charity runs in German spoken countries too, but they almost always have English names, because it sounds so unusual in German:

- [Vienna Charity Run](https://vienna-charityrun.at)
- [Pink Ribbon Lauf](http://www.pinkribbonlauf.com)

Or you only say »Spendenlauf« (which is *charity run*):

- [Hand in Hand Spendenlauf](http://www.handinhand-spendenlauf.de) *(Hand in Hand Charity Run)*

Comment: Der "Hand in Hand Spendenlauf" müsste eigentlich richtig mit Bindestrichen geschrieben werden. Da es ein Eigenname ist, lassen wir ihm das mal durchgehen.

Comment: @tofro: Ich habs mit Copy&Paste von der Website geholt

Answer (score 1):

*Lauf für Essen* is the imperative form as in *Run for food!* while *Laufen für Essen* is the infinitive (to run for food).

This sounds like a competition or charity event. You can chose either but personally I'd go with the *Laufen für Essen*. If this is not the case, maybe you could specify a little further, so we can try to find a more fitting translation.

Comment: This is more of a motto rather than a call to action, so I would say that the imperative form is a little more appropriate in this case right?

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: We still are left alone in the fog what type of event this is, and I think knowing this is necessary for giving a good answer. In the meantime I vote for **Laufen für Saufen**.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd go for a crisp expression, you would probably choose something like

> Tafellauf

Knowing "[die Tafel](https://www.tafel.de)" is a German charity organisation that collects leftover food for the poor and the word sounds similar to *Staffellauf* (relay race) in German.

EDIT: And, someone already seems to have had the same idea: A quick search on the internet shows some charity runs that were actually named like that.

Comment: Das vermeidet immerhin die Mehrdeutigkeit von Essen, "Lauf für Essen", "Radtour für  Dortmund". :) "Nahrung" wäre auch eine Möglichkeit.